# How to highlight clicked div?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a series of divs like this:

```
<div id="listofstuff">
    <div id="anitem">
        <span class="itemname">Item1</h3></span>
        <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="anitem">
        <span class="itemname">Item2</h3></span>
        <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="anitem">
        <span class="itemname">Item3</h3></span>
        <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make to so when the user clicks on an "anitem", the one that was clicked is highlighted and the itemname only pops up in an alertbox.

Comment: `id`s should be unique. You should never have more than one item on a page with a particular `id` value

Comment: Hire me, and I will do your's work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Description

At first i have to say that `id's` must be unique in your document, choose a class instead.
Then you can use jQuerys `click()` and `css()` method to change something.

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the id attribute value must be unique within the HTML document).

Check out my sample and **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/EpHhW/)**

#### Sample

```
<div id="listofstuff">
<div class="anitem">
       <span class="itemname">Item1</h3></span>
       <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem1</span>
</div>
<div class="anitem">
       <span class="itemname">Item2</h3></span>
       <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem2</span>
</div>
<div class="anitem">
       <span class="itemname">Item3</h3></span>
       <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem3</span>
</div>
</div>


$(".anitem").click(function() {
   $(this).css("backgroundColor", "red"); 
});
```

#### More Information

- **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/EpHhW/)**
- [w3c - HTML id Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)
- [jQuery - .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [jQuery - .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 2):

First - you have multiple id parameters with the same value - it's wrong.ID must be unique. I've changed it to class. So instead of `<div id="anitem">` there is `<div class="anitem">`

```
$(function() {
    $('.anitem').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#d00');
        alert($(this).find('.itemname').html());
    })
})
```

Comment: I just about to post same thing, but using Highlight class instead of changing css in click event :-) Here is sample: http://jsfiddle.net/K79AB/2/

Comment: Thanks, this works for strange nestings of unique divs, exactly what I was looking for.