# Make auto-selection of text act like normal selection

Tags: javascript, iphone

I'm working on an answer to a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529599/make-text-more-selectable/35530218#35530218) and have a problem.

Aim is to make text within a tag selectable like you could do on the iphone (with text getting larger on long-touch and you can look where to start your selection), but with a larger clickable area around the text. To see what I mean, please [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jknnou4r/5/) and click into the bordered area.

Right now it auto-selects the text within a given p tag but you can't search where to start.

Code so far

```
function extendSelection() {
    var extendBy = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? 15 : arguments[0];

    var extended = document.getElementsByClassName('extendedSelection');
    [].slice.call(extended).forEach(function (v) {
        var bounds = v.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = bounds.left;
        var r = textWidth(v.innerHTML, ''+ css(v, 'font-weight') +' ' + css(v, 'font-size') + ' ' + css(v, 'font-family') );
        var y = bounds.top;
        var w = bounds.width;
        var h = bounds.height;
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.style.position = 'absolute';
        element.style.height = h + extendBy + 'px';
        element.style.width = r + extendBy + 'px';
        element.style.left = x - extendBy / 2 + 'px';
        element.style.top = y - extendBy / 2 + 'px';
        element.style.border = '1px dotted black';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            SelectText(v);
        });
        element.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
            SelectText(v);
        });
    });
}

function css(element, property) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(property);
}

function textWidth(text, font) {
    var el = textWidth.canvas || (textWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
    var draw = el.getContext("2d");
    draw.font = font;
    var m = draw.measureText(text);
    return m.width;
};

function SelectText(element) {
    var doc = document,
        text = element,
        range,
        selection;
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        selection.setSelectionRange(0, element.value.length)
    }
}

extendSelection();
```